# glfwOpenWindow returns error

Tags: c++, glfw

I'm trying to open a window in glfw using:

```
if( !glfwOpenWindow( 1024, 768, 0,0,0,0, 32,0, GLFW_WINDOW ) ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window\n" );
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
```

except this prints `Failed to open GLFW window`. What's wrong with this?

Comment: Use the glfwSetErrorCallback function to get the error number and description, this will greatly help in debugging this issue. Instructions on how to set this up can be found on the glfw website.

Comment: Have you called `glfwInit` somewhere beforehand?

Comment: Yeah, it's the first thing in the main function.

Comment: can you post a bit more code, there might be something before that is causing the problem.